# Python - Get non NaN value of each variable in a Datafame Based on Latest Iteration

Tags: python, pandas

how to choose each variable based on its latest iteration, grouped by id, non NaN value.
My dataframe looks like this

| unique_id | iteration | variable_1 | variable_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | apple | NaN |
| 111 | 2 | NaN | table |
| 111 | 3 | orange | NaN |
| 111 | 4 | pear | NaN |
| 111 | 5 | NaN | chair |

The expected outcome should be

| unique_id | iteration | variable_1 | variable_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 5 | pear | chair |

Also suppose there will be many unique_id

Comment: Though coming to see this post a bit late, you can still take a look at my answer for your reference.  Hope useful to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.fillna(method="ffill")
```

[see documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

> Method to use for filling holes in reindexed Series pad / **ffill**: propagate last valid observation forward.

---

after that you can reverse a sorting and drop duplicates, essentially getting only 1 entry per "group":

```
df = df.sort_values(["unique_id", "iteration"], ascending=False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(["unique_id", "iteration"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it simply by using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`GroupBy.last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html), as follows:

```
df.groupby('unique_id', as_index=False).last()
```

[`GroupBy.last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) automatically gets the last non-NaN values from each column being aggregated.  Hence, this matches exactly your requirement and is among all the simplest code to use for your requirement.

**Result:**

```
   unique_id  iteration variable_1 variable_2
0        111          5       pear      chair
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slicing, [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), and indexing to get the value for each column separately, then put them into a new `DataFrame` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('unique_id').apply(pd.DataFrame.fillna, method = 'ffill').groupby('unique_id').tail(1)
```

This will both forward fill missing values per `unique_id` and give the last row for each `unique_id`, instead of forward filling values over the whole DataFrame to then get last row for each `unique_id`.

Example df:

```
    unique_id   iteration   variable_1  variable_2
0   111         1           apple       NaN 
1   111         2           NaN         table
2   222         3           orange      table
3   222         4           pear        NaN 
4   111         5           NaN         chair
```

Output:

```
    unique_id   iteration   variable_1  variable_2
3   222         4           pear        table
4   111         5           apple       chair
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df = df.sort_values('iteration')
df = df.groupby('unique_id').ffill().reset_index()
df.iloc[df.groupby('unique_id')['iteration'].idxmax()]
```